# JWT Authentication & Authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, passport.js

I'm trying to find a way to protect each user resource from another user that is correctly authorized. So this is the wrong flow:

[image]

As you can see, Alice has the right JWT token and she is able to get Johns information if she (somehow) manages to get John's id. I want to protect this from happening... How can I do it?

This is the code I'm using for passport authentication. Everything works fine, I'm just trying to add that extra layer of security.

> passportTest.js

```
'use strict';
// load environment variables
require('dotenv').config();
/**
*Module dependencies
*/

const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
/**

*Configuration and Settings
*/
const utilities = require('../models/utilities');

const errHandler = utilities.errHandler;
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const jwtOptions = {
  // Telling Passport to check authorization headers for JWT
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
  // Telling Passport where to find the secret
  secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET
};


// Configure Passport to use JWT strategy to look up Users.
passport.use('jwt', new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function (jwt_payload, done) {
  User.findById({ _id: jwt_payload._doc._id }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err, false);
    }

    if (user) {
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
      return done(null, false);
    }
  })
}));


passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
},
  function (req, email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return errHandler(err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {
          errMsg: 'User does not exist, please' +
          ' <a class="errMsg" href="/signup">signup</a>'
        });
      }

      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { errMsg: 'Invalid password try again' });
      }

      return done(null, user);
    });

  }));
/**
*Export Module
*/
module.exports = passport;
```

> Routes.js

```
'use strict';
// load environment variables
require('dotenv').config();
/**
*Module dependencies
*/
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('../config/passport');
const authChecker = require('../config/authentication-checker');
const passportTest = require('../config/passport-jwt');
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const utilities = require('../models/utilities');
const userController = require('../controllers/user.controller');
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

//==============================================================================
/**
*Create router instance
*/
var router = express.Router();
//==============================================================================
/**
*Module Variables
*/
//needed to protect the '/dashboard' route
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    passportTest.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) { return res.status(401); }

      if (user) {
        req.user = user;
        return next();
      } else {
        return res.status(401);
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  } else {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }
}
//==============================================================================
/**
*Middleware
*/
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
// Authenticate the user and get a JSON Web Token to include in the header of future requests.
router.route('/auth').post((req, res, next) => {
  passportTest.authenticate('local-login', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(409).render('pages/login', { errMsg: info.errMsg });
    }
    req.login(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(409);
      }
      return res.status(200).json(generateToken(user));
    });
  })(req, res, next);
}
);

// Example of required auth: protect dashboard route with JWT
router.get('/secure', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
  return res.send('It worked' + req.user);
});
router.route('/signup')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    return res.render('pages/signup');
  })
  .post(function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', function (err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
      }
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(409).render('pages/signup', { errMsg: info.errMsg });
      }
      req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return next(err);
        }
        return res.redirect('/dashboard');
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
router.route('/api/users/id/:id').get(isLoggedIn, userController.getUserById)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add userId to JWT claim (payload). Then you always can check

```
if (claim.userId !== request.params.userId) {
    res.status(403);
    return next();
}
```

Comment: Where Sergey? In the users controller?

Comment: This check you will do in the endpoint controller. JWT claim you can set when you issue JWT. Refer to password's documentation to figure out how it works.

Comment: I've managed to put it working. Using this method is possible to start using a microservices approach also?

Comment: Yes! JWT extremely useful for micro services, because you can authenticate them when them communicate with each other.

Comment: Sergey Yarotskiy sorry for bother you, but doing this database validation in all endpoints is not overkill?

Comment: You totally flexible to decide here. For some services/endpoints we do it always. For some newer. One more query to postgres gives us + ~2ms to response time in our software. Removing this is micro-optimisation. But you also can store tokens in something like redis if you have a huge user base and hitting performance.

Comment: Sergey Yarotskiy sorry to insistant :D but I'm developing while learning, do you think this approach could be used in a SaaS platform with sensitive data? To explain better: many users with many patients, but each user only has access to his patients. Do you think that is secure enough?

Comment: For sure. Just don't forget to use https. It is crucial when using JWT.

Comment: I've tried to use the Jwt.io platform and I was able of falsifying the JWT token. But if I do that in my application is mission critical, anyone can have access to the data :(

Comment: JWT uses sha256 by default. You cracked this hash function??? Post scientific article then. :-) Jokes aside you just doing something wrong.